# "Mail something", "Send something in the/by mail"

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary, phrases

Are the following phrases correct?

To **mail a package**

To **send** something, other than an envelope, **in the mail**

To **put** something, other than an envelope, **in the mail for someone**

To send something, other than an envelope, **by mail**

I don't know where I've gotten the idea that mail is usually used for envelopes, and packages are normally shipped.

Comment: Do you have a preference for English dialect or location? It might make a difference here.

Comment: Well, I live in Los Angeles, and I moved here a year ago, so I'm not sure if there is a specific terminology specific to here.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct

> **envelopes**

are ***mailed*** and

> **packages**

are ***shipped***.

An ambiguity occurs since smaller packages, which can be carried by hand are also said to be ***mailed***, whereas *larger packages*, which need lifting equipment, or *containers* are said to be ***shipped***.

Comment: I don’t think this distinction is as clear as you make it (at least not in AmE ) I just asked my husband to mail my sister’s birthday present which was a package of significant size. Companies ship packages to me, but if I take a package to the post office, I mail it, not ship it. Maybe I would ship it if I were fulfilling a business transaction instead of sending it to my family though.

Comment: Native AmE speaker here. I use both "mail" and "ship" to refer to what I do with packages. "Ship" does feel a bit more formal. Either (as @ColleenV said) it's part of a business transaction, or maybe I'm sending it a very long way—overseas, probably. And regardless of distance, or whether it's business, I would always say I was "mailing" an envelope.

Comment: That's what I had been leaning toward. "Shipment" is a term I hear more often in business settings - and sounding like postoffice terminology- than in informal conversations. I don't remember hearing things like, _I'm shipping a package today_...